# postgresql conditionally generating value for each row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to implement a simple search functionalitu over links.name column. I would like to match keywords against name values and wanted to get the names with more matchings on the top of result.
What I want/tried to do is

```
declare matchings integer := 0
select if "keyword1" ~* name then matchings := matchings + 1 end if
       if "keyword2" ~* name then matchings := matchings + 1 end if
       ... so on for all keywords given ..
       as matchings_count from links order by matchings_count;
```

What is the correct syntax of doing this? Not bothering about performance since links contain only 1200 rows and not going to increase more than 1500.
Any inputs will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is this a rails question?

Comment: @jvillian, sice im on rails and seeking attention of those who are not watching postgresql tag and know stuff like this. also Answe works with activerecord query interface will be helpful since it contains two statements.

Comment: I don’t know Postgres we’ll. Is this operator - “~*”, - is a fuzzy string match?

Comment: @ЯрославМашко its very much same as like '%keyword%' in mysql, case insensitive.

Comment: Why are you not doing the matching and count in the database? Or is that supposed to be an attempt to express your query but in "rails" language?

Comment: @RichardHuxton I want to count the number of matchings in a given list of keywords against a column for each row. expressing query in rails isn't a big deal.

Comment: Use ‘case when’ construct. ‘select count( case when x ~* ‘keyword’ then 1 when ... ) from t’

Comment: @ЯрославМашко so when more than one keyword matches, it will be only one case triggered right?

Comment: Yes. Your ‘count’ on ‘case’ that returns one when it matches a keyword. You still can use ‘keyword1|keyword2’ regexp in the where clause. As a second thought I think it will be simplier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can convert a boolean to a number and add them up:

```
select l.*,
       ( ("keyword1" ~* name)::int +
         ("keyword2" ~* name)::int +
         . . .
       ) as num_matches         
from links l
order by num_matches desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, that served the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do your task is

```
with t as(
 select 'key1' as k
 union all select 'key2' as k
 union all select 'key3' as k
)

select count(*) from t
where k ~* '(key1)|(key2)'
;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/691c5/3/0)

If you want to just count the number of matchings

```
select count(*) from t
where k ~* 'key1'
union all select count(*) from t
where k ~* 'key2'
...
;
```

Comment: only upvoting since expecting an answer with if-then-else used. if not will accept the answer

Comment: You can wrap the code in CTE and do your ordering, limiting and such.